# JS: Set animation duration for change of src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script for change img on click function

```
    var fstSrc = 'img/1.jpg';
    var sndSrc = 'img/2.jpg';
    var trdSrc = 'img/3.jpg';
    $(".aktualita1").click(function () {
        $('img[src="' + sndSrc + '"]').attr('src', fstSrc);
        $('img[src="' + trdSrc + '"]').attr('src', fstSrc);
    });
```

When click, image changes immidiately, of course. How could i set a 0.5s duration for this click, so images will change with nice fade animation? :) Thanks!

Comment: Image src changes are not animatable. You can fake this by fading containers (or images) in and out. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/byoxxjmu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `fadeOut` change the src of the image and then `fadeIn` giving you the desired effect.

```
var fstSrc = 'img/1.jpg';
var sndSrc = 'img/2.jpg';
var trdSrc = 'img/3.jpg';
$(".aktualita1").click(function () {
    $('img[src="' + sndSrc + '"], img[src="' + trdSrc + '"]').fadeOut(250, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', fstSrc);
    }).fadeIn(250)
});
```

If you want the image to fade on top of the other one, consider using another image element on top of that one (or viceversa).

For example:

```js
var fstSrc = 'https://i.imgur.com/EUym7Pw.jpg';
var sndSrc = 'https://i.imgur.com/Xt8ICog.jpg';
var trdSrc = 'https://i.imgur.com/Fp2EwFc.jpg';
$(".aktualita1").click(function() {
  $('img[src="' + sndSrc + '"], img[src="' + trdSrc + '"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
      var pos = $(this).position();
      $(this).parent().append($('<img src="' + fstSrc + '">').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: pos.left,
        top: pos.top,
        display: 'none'
      }).fadeIn(500));
      $(this).fadeOut(500);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.aktualita1 {
  position: relative;
}
.aktualita1 img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aktualita1">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Xt8ICog.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Fp2EwFc.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: When I use this, it fade to white and then fade to another image. Am I doing something wrong? :/

Comment: Oh, when you said crossfade you meant to have the other image fade on top?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sorry, my fault.

Comment: I tried `$('img[src="' + sndSrc + '"]').attr('src', fstSrc).fadeIn(500);` but nope, I'm doing it wrong :-D. I just want to fade fstSrc over sndSrc (in this example), sorry for missunderstanding.

Comment: @HonzisNovák, you'd need to have the image in a different layer. The images should be about the same size for it to transition smoothly.